# EditText widget in a ListView in a Tabactivty on Android 4.01 Ice Cream Sandwich Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android, android-edittext, galaxy

SOLVED:

I have solved my problem. I've done something else in order to get the desired functionality. It turns out that having a tabHost in a scrollView was the problem, but its only a problem for Android 4.0+ as far as i have tested. The code below enables me to "shrink" my tabwidget which enables my app to go "fullscreen". I hope that this will some day help some one xD.

```
public class MyScaler extends ScaleAnimation
{
    private View         mView;

    private LayoutParams mLayoutParams;

    private int          mMarginBottomFromY, mMarginBottomToY;

    private boolean      mVanishAfter = false;

    public MyScaler(float fromX, float toX, float fromY, float toY, int duration, View view, boolean vanishAfter)
    {
        super(fromX, toX, fromY, toY);
        setDuration(duration);
        mView = view;
        mVanishAfter = vanishAfter;
        mLayoutParams = (LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        final int height = mView.getHeight();

        if(fromY > toY)
        {
            mMarginBottomFromY = (int) (height * fromY) + mLayoutParams.bottomMargin - height;
            mMarginBottomToY = (int) (0 - ((height * toY) + mLayoutParams.bottomMargin)) - height;

        }
        else
        {
            mMarginBottomFromY = mLayoutParams.bottomMargin;
            mMarginBottomToY = 0;
            mView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t)
    {
        super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);

        if (interpolatedTime < 1.0f)
        {
            int newMarginBottom = mMarginBottomFromY + (int) ((mMarginBottomToY - mMarginBottomFromY) * interpolatedTime);
            mLayoutParams.setMargins(mLayoutParams.leftMargin, mLayoutParams.topMargin, mLayoutParams.rightMargin, newMarginBottom);
            mView.getParent().requestLayout();
        }
        else if (mVanishAfter)
        {
            mView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else if(!mVanishAfter)
        {
            mLayoutParams.setMargins(mLayoutParams.leftMargin, mLayoutParams.topMargin, mLayoutParams.rightMargin, 0);
            mView.getParent().requestLayout();
        }

    }



}
```

Hi all :) I’ve worked with Android/iOS for a little more than a year and I have done C/C++ for about 5 as a hobby. This code in question is also a hobby project.

I have a fairly specific question... I'm currently developing my app on a Galaxy Nexus Running out of the box **Android 4.01** i've also tested this on 4.02 - same.

My problem is:

I have several edittext views in LineayLayouts in a listview using a subclass of a BaseAdapter. Whenever i double click or "longclick" this view and it contains text my app crashes and throws an IllegalStateException. See call stack below.. Normally this would (in Android 4.0+ and I’m guessing 3.2+) create an option bar with different copy/paste options.

My App consists of a Tabactivity with 4 tabs. These tabs are made through 4 "child activities". My Tabhost is surrounded by a scrollview in order to make my able to go "fullscreen" and remove the tabwidget, but i don't think that’s the problem. My problem exists in all the 4 tabs.

All of the above works perfectly on 4 other devices, including: HTC Desire, Samsung Galaxy S 2, HTC Hero, and an emulator running 2.3.3. (I can't run the 4.0 emulator on my i7 1.6 quad because it will only use 1/8 of the processing power)

However when I have an Edittext-view in a pop-up like a AlertDialog then the double click / long click functionality in order to mark text works just fine, and the new 4.0 bar in the top of the screen with options like cut, copy, and paste pops up and works just fine.

I've tried to search for a solution myself and on the web but I’ve been unable to find any info. I've found that people have experienced problems with edittext and Listviews before. And I’ve tried putting my Edittext views in LinearLayouts in one huge LinearLayout instead of the Listview but this didn't make any difference.

Any input would be greatly appreciated! Please tell me if you need more info! :)
Thx :)

Edit:

I've done some more research and i've tried to build an app with the exact same layout but without the scrollview surrounding my tabhost. This works. But does not solve my problem unless i want to rewrite most of my layout.

This is my Main.xml

```
<my.pack.MyScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">          

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/ScrollLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TabHost 
            android:id="@android:id/tabhost"   android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/tabs" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="0px"
                    android:layout_margin="0px" android:background="@drawable/horizontaltabbackground">

                    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="0px" android:layout_margin="0px" />

                </HorizontalScrollView>

                <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#ff000000"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </TabHost>

    </LinearLayout>

</my.pack.MyScrollView>
```

Call stack from Eclipse:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception IllegalStateException)) 
    ActionBarContextView.onMeasure(int, int) line: 328  
    ActionBarContextView(View).measure(int, int) line: 12603    
    LinearLayout(ViewGroup).measureChildWithMargins(View, int, int, int, int) line: 4677    
    LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(View, int, int, int, int, int) line: 1369 
    LinearLayout.measureVertical(int, int) line: 660    
    LinearLayout.onMeasure(int, int) line: 553  
    LinearLayout(View).measure(int, int) line: 12603    
    PhoneWindow$DecorView(ViewGroup).measureChildWithMargins(View, int, int, int, int) line: 4677   
    PhoneWindow$DecorView(FrameLayout).onMeasure(int, int) line: 293    
    PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(int, int) line: 2072    
    PhoneWindow$DecorView(View).measure(int, int) line: 12603   
    FrameLayout(ViewGroup).measureChildWithMargins(View, int, int, int, int) line: 4677 
    FrameLayout.onMeasure(int, int) line: 293   
    FrameLayout(View).measure(int, int) line: 12603 
    LinearLayout(ViewGroup).measureChildWithMargins(View, int, int, int, int) line: 4677    
    LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(View, int, int, int, int, int) line: 1369 
    LinearLayout.measureVertical(int, int) line: 660    
    LinearLayout.onMeasure(int, int) line: 553  
    LinearLayout(View).measure(int, int) line: 12603    
    TabHost(ViewGroup).measureChildWithMargins(View, int, int, int, int) line: 4677 
    TabHost(FrameLayout).onMeasure(int, int) line: 293  
    TabHost(View).measure(int, int) line: 12603 
    LinearLayout(ViewGroup).measureChildWithMargins(View, int, int, int, int) line: 4677    
    LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(View, int, int, int, int, int) line: 1369 
    LinearLayout.measureVertical(int, int) line: 660    
    LinearLayout.onMeasure(int, int) line: 553  
    LinearLayout(View).measure(int, int) line: 12603    
    MyScrollView(ScrollView).measureChildWithMargins(View, int, int, int, int) line: 1163   
    MyScrollView(FrameLayout).onMeasure(int, int) line: 293 
    MyScrollView(ScrollView).onMeasure(int, int) line: 312  
    MyScrollView(View).measure(int, int) line: 12603    
    FrameLayout(ViewGroup).measureChildWithMargins(View, int, int, int, int) line: 4677 
    FrameLayout.onMeasure(int, int) line: 293   
    FrameLayout(View).measure(int, int) line: 12603 
    LinearLayout(ViewGroup).measureChildWithMargins(View, int, int, int, int) line: 4677    
    LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(View, int, int, int, int, int) line: 1369 
    LinearLayout.measureVertical(int, int) line: 660    
    LinearLayout.onMeasure(int, int) line: 553  
    LinearLayout(View).measure(int, int) line: 12603    
    PhoneWindow$DecorView(ViewGroup).measureChildWithMargins(View, int, int, int, int) line: 4677   
    PhoneWindow$DecorView(FrameLayout).onMeasure(int, int) line: 293    
    PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(int, int) line: 2072    
    PhoneWindow$DecorView(View).measure(int, int) line: 12603   
    ViewRootImpl.performTraversals() line: 1044 
    ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(Message) line: 2418  
    ViewRootImpl(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
    Looper.loop() line: 137 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4340    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 784  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 551 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Comment: hi 'Professional Android Developer' :) I thought TabActivity's were deprecated in 4.0...

Comment: TabActivity's are deprecated yup. But i like the functionality it provides me.